# Proper way of giving border around RecyclerView elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with vertical `LinearLayoutManager`. I have to give a border around the elements of this `recyclerView`.

My approach was to create a `drawable` with `rectangle` shape having a `stroke` with the border colour and set this `drawable` as the background of the row of `recyclerView`.

Here is my background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#979797" />

    <solid android:color="#424447" />

</shape>
```

The problem with this approach was that the inside borders of the rows (visualise it as dividers for vertical list) are getting drawn of twice the required width due to the overlapping of bottom and top of rectangle backgrounds, whereas I want all borders of same width.

So, I tried putting 4 views along the four sides of the row's `layout` and thought about manipulating `visibility` of individual borders based on it's position. Here is my layout for the row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!--android:background="@drawable/background_collection">-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/collectionThumb"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/collectionThumb"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/collectButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/collectionThumb"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/collectButton"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/collectionName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#F0F0E9"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#8a8a8a"
                android:textSize="8dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/collectButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_collect_default" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topBorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#979797" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomBorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#979797" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/leftBorder"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#979797" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/rightBorder"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#979797" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/triangleTip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20.9dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20.9dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shape_top_arrow_fancy"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the left and right borders are not appearing. I guess that those views are not able to calculate their height. I thought that I would calculate the row's height and manually give the left and right borders this height. So, I tried finding the `height` of the top `ViewGroup` with `id` as `container` in `onBindViewHolder()` of `recyclerView's` `adapter`. I tried using `getHeight()`, `getMeasuredHeight()` and even using `LayoutParams`, but I am not getting the correct `height`. Using `LayoutParams`, I am getting `height` as `-2` and `0` in other cases.

How do I solve this problem? Is my approach correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Chisko No, I didn't try. What's the use of that in this situation?

Comment: Even if I get the values, what's the use of that? How will that solve my problem? I don't want to hardcode values.

Comment: use `cardView` with recyclerView

Comment: @rookieDeveloper dude, how will cardView help here?

Comment: use a [nine patch drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

Comment: Set the same drawable as the background of the recyclerview, that should even out the thickness of the border